site it doesn't stop loading in all devices
By opening my WordPress site it doesn't stop loading in all devices (PC-Mobile-tablet) so it doesn't open despite I do all the updates for all plugins an my theme (eduma)
What is the reasons and the solutions for this eror.

The issue may be caused by a conflict between plugins or a problem with the Eduma theme's compatibility after updates. Disable all plugins and switch to a default theme to identify the cause, then re-enable them one by one.

There could be multiple reasons for your WordPress site's persistent loading problem even after updates. First, following upgrades, make sure that your theme (Eduma) and plugins are compatible. Plugins or theme files that are out of date might occasionally cause issues. Second, check the console of your browser for any JavaScript issues that might be preventing the website from loading. Such problems can also be fixed by removing superfluous plugins and cleaning the cache. Finally, take into account resource constraints and server performance to make sure your hosting can support the demands of the website. By following these steps methodically, you should be able to identify and fix the loading issue on all devices.
